# How to check when a for loop has finished, inside the loop?

Tags: javascript

Here is a quick jsfiddle I made to give a better example of my question.

```
function gi(id){return document.getElementById(id)}

    a= [1,5,1,2,3,5,3,4,3,4,3,1,3,6,7,752,23]


for(i=0; i < a.length; i++){
    /*
    if (WHAT AND WHAT){ What do I add here to know that the last value in the array was used? (For this example, it's the number: 23. Without doing IF==23.

    }
    */

    gi('test').innerHTML+=''+a[i]+' <br>';
}
```

(the code is also available at https://jsfiddle.net/qffpcxze/1/)

So, the last value in that array is 23, but how can I know that the last value was looped in, inside the loop itself? (Without checking for a simple `IF X == 23`, but dynamically), if that makes sense.

Comment: Didn't you ask enough questions to know the relevant code should be IN the question ?

Comment: In SO you MUST post the important code on SO we don't do links to all your code.  Please post the import bit here and link to the rest

Comment: What do you mean? It's on jsfiddle, isn't it easier on there to debug it live?
Edit: Oh, you want the code included and a fiddle link as well. My bad. Will do in the future, sorry about that!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Write an `if` statement which compares the arrays length with `i`

```
if(a.length - 1 === i) {
    console.log('loop ends');
}
```

Or you can use a ternary

```
(a.length - 1 === i) ? console.log('Loop ends') : '';
```

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/qffpcxze/2/)

Also note that am using `- 1` because array index starts from `0` and the length is returned counting from `1` so to compare the array with length we negate `-1` .

Comment: Definitely marking this as best. Reason I ask is I run a dynamic map generator through the loop with json and I need to tell the player when the map objects are finished loading. (Not really probably the best way, as in the images might still be loading, but this way is fine for now.. lol) Thanks @Mr. Alien! Marked as best because you explained the -1 too.

Comment: Also, @Mr. Alien, I would use `Object.keys` (length) if it's within an object for in loop, correct?

Answer (score 5):

```
if (i == a.length - 1) {
     // your code here
```

Answer (score 3):

You can make the condition in if like this:

```
function gi(id){return document.getElementById(id)}
a= [1,5,1,2,3,5,3,4,3,4,3,1,3,6,7,752,23];

for(i=0; i < a.length; i++){
  if (i==(a.length-1)){ //give your condition here
     //your stuff
  }
  gi('test').innerHTML+=''+a[i]+' <br>';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
if(i === a.length - 1) {
    //some code
}
```